# Spring Data Neo4j find nodes by a few arrays of ids

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a query for searching nodes by 3 other relationship nodes:

```
@Query("MATCH " +
        "(n:DTTOVAR)-[cnorr:LIKE_CONSIGNOR]->(consignor:COMPANY), " +
        "(n:DTTOVAR)-[prodr:LIKE_PRODUCER]->(producer:COMPANY), " +
        "(n:DTTOVAR)-[cneer:LIKE_CONSIGNEE]->(consignee:COMPANY), " +
        "WHERE " +
        "id(consignor) in $0 AND id(producer) IN $1 AND id(consignee) IN $2 " +
        "RETURN n, cnorr, prodr, cneer, consignor, producer, consignee")
List<DTTovar> getAllByConsignorsProducersConsigneesPC(Long[] cnorsIds, Long[] producersIds, Long[] cneesIds);
```

But!!! I need if cnorsIds, producersIds or cneesIds will be null, then to exclude this condition from query or search by all. How to do this?

Comment: If a `MATCH` term's id list is null, do you want to ignore that term or do you want it to find all matches?

Comment: if one of term's id list in WHERE is null, I want to find all matches of this term!, but still searching by others. Because if one of lists of ids is null, then all query return 0 nodes (

Comment: May be you are right, will be better to ignore this term and search by others! I think it's equal to searching for all matches of this term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query("OPTIONAL MATCH (n:DTTOVAR)-[cnorr:LIKE_CONSIGNOR]->(consignor:COMPANY) WHERE $0 IS NOT NULL AND id(consignor) IN $0 " +
 "OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[prodr:LIKE_PRODUCER]->(producer:COMPANY) WHERE $1 IS NOT NULL AND id(producer) IN $1 " +
 "OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[cneer:LIKE_CONSIGNEE]->(consignee:COMPANY) WHERE $2 IS NOT NULL AND id(consignee) IN $2 " +
 "OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[coder:CLASSIFIED_IN]->(code:CUSTOMS_CODE) WHERE $3 IS NOT NULL AND id(consignee) IN $3 " +
 "WITH n MATCH (n:DTTOVAR)-[cnorr:LIKE_CONSIGNOR]->(consignor:COMPANY), " +
 "(n)-[prodr:LIKE_PRODUCER]->(producer:COMPANY), " +
 "(n)-[cneer:LIKE_CONSIGNEE]->(consignee:COMPANY), " +
 "(n)-[coder:CLASSIFIED_IN]->(code:CUSTOMS_CODE), " +
 "(n)-[e:REGISTERED_AT]->(d:H_DAY)-[r:DAY_OF]->(m:H_MONTH)-[t:MONTH_OF]->(y:H_YEAR) " +
 "WHERE case $0 IS NULL when FALSE then id(consignor) in $0 else true end " +
 "AND case $1 IS NULL when FALSE then id(producer) in $1 else true end " +
 "AND case $2 IS NULL when FALSE then id(consignee) in $2 else true end " +
 "AND case $3 IS NULL when FALSE then id(code) in $3 else true end " +
 "RETURN n, cnorr, consignor, prodr, producer, cneer, consignee, coder, code, e,d,r,m,t,y")
List<DTTovar> getAllByConsignorsNNAndProducersAndConsigneesAndCustomsCode(Long[] cnorsId, Long[] producersId, Long[] cneesId, Long[] codesId);
```

Comment: But there is need to avoid a case when first OPTIONAL MATCH returns null results

Answer (score 0):

This query logic basically ignores a `MATCH` term if its id list is `null`:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:DTTOVAR)-[cnorr:LIKE_CONSIGNOR]->(consignor:COMPANY)
WHERE $0 IS NOT NULL AND id(consignor) in $0
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[prodr:LIKE_PRODUCER]->(producer:COMPANY)
WHERE $1 IS NOT NULL AND id(producer) IN $1
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[cneer:LIKE_CONSIGNEE]->(consignee:COMPANY)
WHERE $2 IS NOT NULL AND id(consignee) IN $2
RETURN n, cnorr, prodr, cneer, consignor, producer, consignee
```

Using [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) on my version of neo4j, I see that the `IS NOT NULL` test is done *before* the corresponding `OPTIONAL MATCH` term is executed, so this should be efficient (up to a point).

*However, you are still going to get a cartesian product of the results of the terms that are not ignored. It is not clear if that is acceptable to you.*

Comment: A `MATCH` pattern will always fail if anything in the pattern is not found. It does not matter if there is a `WHERE` clause that attempts to make `null` bindings OK. That is why your modified query finds fewer nodes and relationships than mine.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still trying to find another way to combine OPTIONAL MATCH (low db hits) with MATCH (to exclude unwanted nodes) or others ...

Comment: After combining (OPTIONAL MATCH (n) ... WHERE ... ) (OPTIONAL MATCH (n) ... WHERE ... ) ... then WITH n MATCH (n) .... WHERE (all my terms). Total 1676 db hits and as a Result we get wanted nodes!  But the query is very complex, is it possible to find more elegant way?

Comment: What exactly is "all my terms"? Also, do the "unwanted" nodes have any common characteristics that we can use for filtering (that is simpler than "all my terms")?

Comment: For the first we search by using OPTIONAL MATCH, then use WITH n as a result, and then search with the same MATCHes but only in (n) nodes. There is no any characteristics(

Answer (score 0):

Very thanks, cybersam
I have compared my varian and yours:
It's my:
PROFILE MATCH (n:DTTOVAR)-[cnorr:LIKE_CONSIGNOR]->(consignor:COMPANY), (n)-[prodr:LIKE_PRODUCER]->(producer:COMPANY), (n)-[cneer:LIKE_CONSIGNEE]->(consignee:COMPANY), (n)-[coder:CLASSIFIED_IN]->(code:CUSTOMS_CODE) 
WHERE case [7065] IS NULL when FALSE then id(consignor) in [7065] else true end 
AND case null IS NULL when FALSE then id(producer) in null else true end 
AND case [5928, 28769, 7067] IS NULL when FALSE then id(consignee) in [5928, 28769, 7067] else true end 
AND case null IS NULL when FALSE then id(code) in null else true end 
RETURN n, cnorr, consignor, prodr, producer, cneer, consignee, coder, code

72490 total db hits in 79 ms.

And yours:
PROFILE OPTIONAL MATCH (n:DTTOVAR)-[cnorr:LIKE_CONSIGNOR]->(consignor:COMPANY) WHERE [7065] IS NOT NULL AND id(consignor) IN [7065] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[prodr:LIKE_PRODUCER]->(producer:COMPANY) WHERE null IS NOT NULL AND id(producer) IN null 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[cneer:LIKE_CONSIGNEE]->(consignee:COMPANY) WHERE [5928, 28769, 7067] IS NOT NULL AND id(consignee) IN [5928, 28769, 7067] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[coder:CLASSIFIED_IN]->(code:CUSTOMS_CODE) WHERE null IS NOT NULL AND id(code) IN null 
RETURN n, cnorr, consignor, prodr, producer, cneer, consignee, coder, code

716 total db hits in 42 ms

But the counts of (n:DTTOVAR) nodes are different ( there are 152 nodes in your variant vs 105 in my.

I try to understand it ....
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more pictures of results: (there are some unwanted nodes in your variant)

[image]

[image]